# Mockito: Difference between doThrow() and thenThrow()

Tags: mockito

What's the difference between `doThrow()` and `thenThrow()`?

Let's say, we want to mock an authentication service to validate the login credentials of a user. What's the difference between the following two lines if we were to mock an exception?

```
doThrow(new BadCredentialsException("Wrong username/password!")).when(authenticationService).login("user1", "pass1");
```

vs

```
when(authenticationService.login("user1", "pass1")).thenThrow(new BadCredentialsException("Wrong username/password!"));
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Almost nothing: in simple cases they behave exactly the same. The `when` syntax reads more like a grammatical sentence in English.

Why "almost"? Note that the `when` style actually contains a call to `authenticationService.login`. That's the first expression evaluated in that line, so whatever behavior you have stubbed will happen during the call to `when`. Most of the time, there's no problem here: the method call has no stubbed behavior, so Mockito only returns a dummy value and the two calls are exactly equivalent. However, this might not be the case if either of the following are true:

- you're overriding behavior you already stubbed, particularly to run an Answer or throw an Exception
- you're working with a spy with a non-trivial implementation

In those cases, `doThrow` will call `when(authenticationService)` and deactivate all dangerous behavior, whereas `when().thenThrow()` will invoke the dangerous method and throw off your test.

(Of course, for void methods, you'll also need to use `doThrow`—the `when` syntax won't compile without a return value. There's no choice there.)

Thus, `doThrow` is always a little safer as a rule, but `when().thenThrow()` is slightly more readable and usually equivalent.

Comment: I thought the main reason for `doThrow(...).when(...)` was for methods that do not return a value

Comment: @BretC Yes, doVerb works for stubbing void methods, but there's nothing subtle about that; `when` simply won't compile. I'd focused on the more-subtle differences as I see a lot of related questions. Thanks all the same—I'll edit in.

Comment: For reference: https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.4.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#do_family_methods_stubs