# Spying with Mockito

Tags: mockito, spy

As per [THIS](http://www.stevenschwenke.de/spyingWithMockito) post, There are two ways to mock the method doSomeStuff() to return a 1 :

```
when(bloMock.doSomeStuff()).thenReturn(1);
```

and

```
doReturn(1).when(bloMock).doSomeStuff();
```

> The very important difference is that the first option will actually
>   call the doSomeStuff()- method while the second will not

So, my question is what is the point in having the first option which actually calls the actual method but returns 1 only. In which use case, we may want to something like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353846/mockito-difference-between-doreturn-and-when

Comment: Actually I carefully read your question. However, I never heard before the difference you menction (and I just noticed that's described in one of the answers of my linked question). Anyway, I'll be waiting for answers. Thanks for comment :)

Comment: Also think it's a duplicate, your question `what is the point in having the first option` is answered in the accepted answer: `One thing that when/thenReturn gives you, that doReturn/when doesn't, is type-checking of the value that you're returning, at compile time.`

Comment: @BretC If `bloMock` is a spy, it would indeed call the actual method, see http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13. As for the discussion whether this is a duplicate or not, I agree that it is. I suspect that `stub()` (which was refactored to `when()`) existed before `toReturn()` (which was refactored to `thenReturn()`), and that they kept both ways of mocking. I myself prefer the first option in the question, and only use `doReturn()` when using spies or mocking void methods.

Comment: This question reads very much like [this other one here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343149/mockito-difference-between-dothrow-and-thenthrow/36343419), for which the answer is the same: `when` reads like a grammatical sentence in English, and in the case of mocks (not spies) there is no reason not to use the more readable style.

Answer (score 1):

I dug a bit more than this, and the answer to why both syntaxes exist can be found in the old [release notes](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mockito/wikis/ReleaseNotes.wiki), and a referenced [mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mockito/d8MoxBdc_G0).

To start with, `doReturn()` was added in version 1.5 (26/07/2008), while `when()` was added in version 1.6 (21/10/2008). `when()` was implemented to replace the old `stub()` method and `doReturn()` to replace `stubVoid()`. Basically this is a design deicision by the creator of Mockito (cited from the mailing list 29/06/2008):

> I never liked stubVoid() syntax but that was the best I could think
>   of. The stubbing syntax I'd implement now if I did mockito again:
>   
>   //regular stubbing:
>   
>   `when(mock.getStuff()).thenReturn("foo");`
>   `when(mock.getStuff()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());`
>   
>   //for void methods and some corner cases:
>   
>   `doReturn("foo").when(mock).getStuff();`
>   `doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();`
>   
>   //for stubbing consecutively:
>   
>   `when(mock.getStuff()).thenReturn("foo").thenThrow(new RuntimeException());`
>   
>   `doThrow(new RuntimeException()).thenReturn("foo").when(mock).someMethod();`
>   
>   I proposed this syntax couple of weeks ago but received only single
>   feedback saying that it's rather cosmetic (which is true...). Hence I
>   decided not to change the API.

And as already pointed out by [Bewusstsein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3385618/bewusstsein) in the comments, `when()` provides type safety. If we have a method `String doSomething()` both below blocks will compile. The latter will however throw an exception during runtime.

```java
Mockito.doReturn("String").when(mock).doSomething();
Mockito.doReturn(1).when(mock).doSomething();
```

So, to conclude, it was a design decision to introduce both ways of mocking. `when()` was imlemented as the prefered way of mocking, due to its type safety and its fluent reading. `doReturn()` was implemented to allow for mocking of `void` methods and other corner cases.